# Can I select an element which doesn't contain another element?

Tags: html, css

In CSS, can I select an element which doesn't contain another element?

For example:

```
<div>
    <p>ABC</p>
    <p>
        <q>123</q>
    </p>
    <p>ABC</p>
</div>
```

I want to set css for each `p` element, but not for the element which contains `q`.

Is this possible?

Comment: Good spot!  Unfortunately some p elements contain link tags :(

Comment: I've undeleted my JavaScript-based answer as this is probably your only solution here.

Answer (score 2):

If that is what your HTML looks like, you could use a method such as this...

```
div p {
   /* styles */
}

div p q {
  /* styles to *undo* previous styles, plus additional ones */
}
```

Comment: You see, I have a margin set on the p elements which I dont want on the p > q element.  It's also not convenient for me to change or remove the p element containing q.  As commented above, I might be able to use the p:empty selector?

Comment: @PatrickKeane You could if they didn't have element or text nodes, but they do in your example.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a margin set on the p elements which I dont want on the p > q element.

Unfortunately this isn't possible with CSS alone. You can however achieve this with JavaScript (the below example uses [jQuery](http://jquery.com)):

You can combine [`:not`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) and [`:has`](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/):

```js
$('p:not(:has(q))')
```

With this you can then modify the CSS using `.css()`:

```js
$('p:not(:has(q))').css({
    'margin': '5px'
});
```

Here is a [**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/GM7cb/).

Comment: this hasn't been tagged with jquery - I made the same mistake with my answer

Comment: jQuery would be useful, but I'm developing for mobile and I'm leaving as much scripting work to the server side as possible.

Comment: @PatrickKeane if you're leaving the work to the server can you simply not add a separate class to elements with (or without) `q` children?